# unexpected result while evaluating the operators

Tags: java

I have below code and it gives an unexpected result. To my understanding, the result should be 6 but its 1. Can someone help me how to get it?

```
int j = 0;
int i1 = j*5+ ++j;
System.out.println("j =" + j);
System.out.println("i1 =" + i1);
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think the result should be 6 so we can explain where your reasoning goes wrong?

Comment: That's down to operator precedence, see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between getting 6 and getting 1 is whether you think `j*5` will be evaluated first or `++j` will be evaluated first. The rule in Java is that subexpressions are evaluated in the order they appear in the expression if the order is not forced by dependencies. Here, `j*5` appears first in the expression, so it is evaluated first. That gives the `1` result.

Comment: I read that pre-increment has higher precedence. So why j*5 will be evaluated first?

Comment: @zephyr Because `++j` is not in the same expression, so it is still evaluated left to right, putting `j*5` first

Comment: What is subexpression here? How j*5 is subexpression? There is no bracket?

Comment: in `j*5 + ++j` you can *say* that `j*5` is one subexpression and `++j` is another, and they are processed from left to right

Comment: Look at the expression `j*5+ ++j`. Why is this a legal expression in Java? The answer is that `<subexpression> + <subexpression>` is a legal form of an expression. Hence `j*5` and `++j` are two subexpressions. The subexpression `++j` is itself composed of the form `++<subexpression>`. This is how you figure out what an expression does.

Comment: Operator precedence and order of evaluation are not the same thing.  Precedence is how you know ```a+b*c``` means ```a+(b*c)``` and not ```(a+b)*c```.

Comment: If I get it correct then it means that in java the evaluation happens from left to right. But then why we need precedence?

Comment: @zephyr Precedence and order of evaluation are totally different things. Consider `F(A) * G(B) + H(C)`. Order of evaluation determines the order in which you call `F(A)`, `G(B)`, and `H(C)` while precedence determines how you combine the results to get the final result (do you multiply first or add first). Precedence is why `j * 5 + ++j` is the same as `(j * 5) + (++j)` and not `j * (5 + ++j)`. Order of evaluation is why `j*5 + ++j` evaluates `j*5` before evaluating `++j`. Sometimes precedence dictates order of evaluation. The `j` in `j*5` must be evaluated before the addition can be done.

Answer (score -1):

You have something like the code below:

```
int j = 0;
int i1 = j*5+ ++j;
System.out.println("j =" + j);
System.out.println("i1 =" + i1);
```

You need to edit your code to this:

```
int j = 0;
int i1 = ++j*5 + j;
System.out.println("j =" + j);
System.out.println("i1 =" + i1);
```

Your final output for "i1 =" + i1) will be 6. 
The issue is that in your first code sample you are not incrementing J before you multiply it by 5 so you're only increasing it by +1 because you don't actually increment j until you've multiplied 0 * 5. (0 * 5) + 1 = 1. What I did was simply increment j (in prefix form) so that it increments by 1, and now you're multiplying (1 * 5) + 1.

Comment: I want the same expression and want to understand the logic.

Comment: @zephyr That is the logic. You're attempting to multiple j before it has been incremented by 5. If you haven't incremented j, you're going to be multiplying by 0 and not by 1. So your expression doesn't work. As I stated, you need to increment j first, as I showed in the example. Now you're multiplying (1 * 5). If you use your expression you're multiplying (0 * 5) and then you're not incrementing j until after that which is why you get 1.

Comment: @zephyr Does that make more sense now? In your code you haven't incremented j at all until after the multiplication has occurred. If that makes sense you can see why that expression won't work. You have to increment j first because the expression reads from left-to-right just like any math problem here. If you haven't incremented j, you'll end up with (0 * 5), and then you didn't increment j by +1 until after the multiplication occurred. So you won't be able to use the same expression. It doesn't work.

Comment: Could whomever made the down vote explain why? That'd be helpful